# how to handle different targets for multiple submit buttons in a form?

Tags: php, forms

In index.php I have a form:

```
<form name="UserLocation" action="propForSale.php" method="GET">
```

Once the user types in the name of a location in the text box on the form, they click on the "For Sale" submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="For Sale" />
```

This takes the user to propForSale.php page as specified in the action attribute.
But I now have another button on the form in index.php:

```
<input type="submit" value="To Rent" />
```

I now want the user to be directed to "propToRent.php" when they click on the "To Rent" button.

At the moment, it take the user to "propForSale.php" when they click on the "To Rent" button. This is probably because it is specified in the action attribute of the form to go to that particular page. But how do I get it to go to "propToRent.php"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two buttons and use Javascript to change the action of form and submit it to different pages, but I think the drop-down menu is the simpler solution. Anyway, to use two buttons you'll need something like:

```
<form id="userLocation" action="" method="get">
<p>
    <label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="field2">Field 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" />
</p>    
<p>
    <input type="button" value="For Sale" onclick="submitForm('forSale.php')" />
    <input type="button" value="To Rent" onclick="submitForm('toRent.php')" />
</p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(action) {
    form = document.getElementById('userLocation');

    form.action = action;
    form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a name to the submit-buttons. Then you can check `$_POST` for the value and redirect the user.

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to give me an example of how this would be structured?

Comment: HTML: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="To Rent" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="To Sale" />`; but the PHP Code is difficult because a simple redirect using `header('Location: ...')` won't redirect `$_POST` too. So you have to combine `propToRent.php` and `propForSale.php`. In this file you can check `$_POST['submit']` for being `'To Rent'` or `'To Sale'`.

Comment: Note that this does not work in Safari/Webkit as of Safari 8 (Jan 2015)

Answer (score 1):

Do it with a drop-down menu with 2 options. To-Rent or For Sale, then use the current page index.php and check for if

(isset $POST('location'))
{
your submit code
}